# Find the odd one out: Hand signals

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking

Not all of us are familiar with sign language. It is used predominantly by the deaf and people who can hear but cannot speak. But it's not a big deal in understanding some of the hand signals. Even we use sign language like the ones in the below image in our day to day life.

One of these hand signals is different from others. Find the odd one out and state the reason why that signal is different from others.

[image]

Comment: Wow, this question is attracting a lot of bad answers. The trouble with odd-one-out questions is that they're very often too broad.

Comment: K is the only one that'll get you punched.

Comment: M is the different one and ahh I can't post an answer

Comment: Just for the sake of my curiosity, what should have been the correct answer according to you AeJey?

Answer (score 7):

## The answer is...

> L

because

> It is the only letter that is correct in actual sign language.

Comment: D also fits your reasoning

Comment: Which sign language? Each nation has its own.

Comment: D should be pointing up to match ASL. What's shown as D is actually G. I don't know any other sign alphabets.

Comment: Actually, in ASL, the letter G would have thumb extended, running parallel to index finger. Item D above  isn't ASL from what I know (which isn't much beyond the alphabet ;) )

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

> K

Because

> It is the only one with solely negative connotations

Comment: Haha ! I also thought the same :D But even `O` can be considered as threatening someone to punch.

Comment: But O also has positive (non-negative) connotations, rock paper scissors for instance, or a success gesture after scoring a goal. Where as K is only (in English 'speaking' countries) an insult.

Comment: Frequently K is used to point in countries where it doesnt have the familiar meaning.  (Germany is one example)

Comment: @kaine Really? In what parts of germany? I live here 20 years and have never met anyone pointing with the "Stinkefinger" it is known everywhere as a rude gesture!

Comment: I dont know what parts (as i lived in switzerland and this was roughly 15 years ago) but i knew 2 people who defaulted to that who were orginally from germany. One (my tutor in german) said it just didn't have a negative connotation there. Maybe he meant switzerland but he was german and we lived close to the border. It is kind of hard to forget hin pointing to each word with it one the page.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is

> L

Because

> It is the only sign that cannot be done with the other hand. We all know it mean *"loser"* by the *L* shape, but if you do it with left hand, the *L* is reverted, losing its meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I think 'F' is answer, because you can see Thumb Up in 'N'.
But when I try to make sign like 'F', it is not possible.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the fingers are bending backwards in F?

Comment: Both "O" and "F" use the left hand, and the rest use the right hand.

Comment: "K" is as well here based on pinky/ring finger orientation with a back-facing hand. Regardless, it was an interesting thought ^^.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is

> O

Because

> It is the only hand signal in which all the fingers are facing west. Left when looking at the picture.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be

> F

because it is the only one that

> uses the left hand instead of the right one.

Comment: My first thought, but K and O are done with the left hand as well.

Comment: Good point. Seems like I got distracted while double-checking by all the weird looks I was drawing.

Comment: F is the only one that has to be done with the left hand though, otherwise it is a N

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer would be

> C

because all other hand signals

> can be derived from another hand signal by moving at most ONE finger and/or doing reflection (changing hand) or rotation.

For example,

> A can be derived from B, and B from A.
>  D can be derived from H, J, or O.
>  E can be derived from M, and M from E.
>  F can be derived from H, I, L, N, or O.
>  G can be derived from D, H, J, or O.
>  H can be derived from D, F, G, K, N, or O.
>  I can be derived from F, N, or P.
>  J can be derived from D, G, or K.
>  K can be derived from H, J, or O.
>  L can be derived from F, N, or P.
>  N can be derived from F, H, I, L, or O.
>  O can be derived from D, F, G, H, K, or N.
>  P can be derived from I or L.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> D

Because

> It is the only gesture which can be seen when you hold out your arms.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is

> N

Mainly because

> If you notice the hands how we see em in the image is how we would see them if some other person was doing them and we were looking, N is the only one who would feel odd if you saw it like that ( palm looking at you instead of the back of the hand)